# youtube api json-c

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube, json-c

Ok so I am trying to change my script for getting youtube playlist to the uploaded videos from youtube instead, reason I am changing this is because I want to use the username not an id (e.x. 38484937495 to this instead MrEasyBB)

So here is my first script which works but it is a playlist and don't want that anymore...

```
var width= 780;
var height= 420;
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/B2A4E1367126848D?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
var list_data="";
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
    var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
    var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
    var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
    var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
    var url = videoURL + videoID;
    var pubed = item.published.$t;
    var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
    list_data += '<li class="video_info" value="'+ url +'"><img alt="'+ feedTitle+'" src="'+ thumb +'"/><span class="title">'+ feedTitle +'</span><span class="pubed">'+ pubed +'</span></li>';
});
$(list_data).appendTo("#playlist");
});
```

I have started with this and it is not much

```
 var width= 780;
 var height= 420;
 var username = "MrEasyBB";
 var playListURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'+ username +'/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc';
 var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
 $.getJSON(playListURL, function(data){
var list_data="";
$.each(function(i, item) {
var title = item.data.items[0].title;
   var description = item.data.items[0].description;
   var pubbd = item.data.items[0].uploaded;
   var videoID = item.data.items[0].id;
   var url = videoURL + videoID;
    var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
    list_data += '<li class="video_info" value="'+ url +'"><img alt="'+ feedTitle+'" src="'+ thumb +'"/><span class="title">'+ feedTitle +'</span><span class="pubed">'+ pubed +'</span></li>';
});
$(list_data).appendTo("#playlist");
});
```

As you can see I haven't gotten very far to the second code because once I change the `var playListURL` to the json c link it won't work to me. I tried changing the var in the each... Maybe I should get rid of the .each? Not sure really. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have updated the post with my second try. It is not getting any errors, though it is not parsing any data out?

Comment: Never mind I have figured this out myself. Thank you anyways for the no help lol. I will post an answer later for people to see and understand.